# React project can't detect any change in app.js file

Tags: reactjs

React project can't detect any change in app.js file
This is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>I'm a react app!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed64l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text **I'm a react app!** inside a div.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>I'm a react app!</div>
        );
    }
} export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `ReactDOM` to help tell app where to render your component.  For instance, if you create a `div` in your HTML like `<div id="root"></div>`, then you could use the following code:

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I'm a react app!</div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Also note that when you return your render, the result should be wrapped in a single tag.